# Disable java Security

Tags: java, internet-explorer-10

I'm using Java <s>7u21</s> 7u80 on an Intranet computer. I would like to completely disable java security to prevent any dialogs or messages.

Is there a way to do this in the Java settings or Group Policy?

Note: The browser is accessing an intranet site, I'm using IE 10 on Windows 7.

Comment: The version of Java your using doesn't have the required control panel applet.  Consider installing the current version of Java 7 in order to acomplish your goals.

Comment: @Ramhound - I updated java to 7u80, how do I do this in that version?

Comment: Go to the `Control Panel` then search for `Java`

Comment: @Ramhound - But change what? I have the security tab set on medium and the site whitelisted but I need all prompts to stop and it doesn't.